# Clear TEdit control rad studio delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rad-studio

When use TEdit control on the right side stay small icon 'x'.  How after click on icon clear TEdit box.

Tnx all!

[image]

Comment: VCL or FireMonkey?

Comment: @Sami FireMonkey

Comment: @Sami  I'm create new blank mobile and device app and add TEdit control. Afrer click on 'X' nothing happens. I'm beginner.

Comment: I create a new blank project with `TEdit` and `TClearEditButton`, the button works just fine. (Delphi 10 Seattle)

Comment: @Sami That is TEdit button!

Comment: I believe there are should be event for this button. Just assign a handler to this event and write a code inside that handler to cler `TEdit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delphi provide `TClearEditButton` to clear the `TEdit` content. It can be added by right clicking and selecting `AddItem - TClearEditButton` from the popup menu. It also has a Click procedure overriden in FMX.Edit unit like:

```
procedure TClearEditButton.Click;
var
  EditTmp: TCustomEdit;
begin
  inherited Click;
  EditTmp := GetEdit;
  if EditTmp <> nil then
  begin
    if EditTmp.Observers.IsObserving(TObserverMapping.EditLinkID) then
      if not TLinkObservers.EditLinkEdit(EditTmp.Observers) then
        Exit; // Can't change
    EditTmp.Text := string.Empty;
    if EditTmp.Observers.IsObserving(TObserverMapping.EditLinkID) then
      TLinkObservers.EditLinkModified(EditTmp.Observers);
    if EditTmp.Observers.IsObserving(TObserverMapping.ControlValueID) then
      TLinkObservers.ControlValueModified(EditTmp.Observers);
  end;
end;
```

Which make you don't need to write `OnClick` event handler for the `TClearEditButton` unless you want to do some other job along side with clearing the edit.

If you are using a `TEditButton` then you should write the `OnClick` event handler like:

```
procedure TForm1.EditButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text:= EmptyStr;
end;
```